# Pandas Timedelta is negative where it should be positive, how to overcome the limitations

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I want to calculate difference between the day smth was mentioned and the day it was published. So I have the next DataFrame

```
df_test= pd.DataFrame([{'Mention Date': pd.Timestamp('2015-09-17 12:47:06'),
                        'Publication Date': pd.Timestamp('1684-01-01 00:00:00')},
                        {'Mention Date': pd.Timestamp('2015-09-17 12:47:06'),
                        'Publication Date': pd.Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00')},
                        {'Mention Date': pd.Timestamp('2015-09-17 12:47:06'),
                        'Publication Date': pd.Timestamp('1724-01-01 00:00:00')},
                        {'Mention Date': pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01'),
                        'Publication Date': pd.Timestamp('1722-09-22 00:12:43.1453')},
                        {'Mention Date': pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01'),
                        'Publication Date': pd.Timestamp('1722-09-22 00:00:00')}])
```

Now I want to calculate the difference between "Mention Date" and "Publication Date".

```
print df_test["Mention Date"] - df_test["Publication Date"]

0    -92350 days +13:12:32.290448
1               989 days 12:47:06
2            106545 days 12:47:06
3     106751 days 23:47:16.854700
4   -106752 days +00:25:26.290448
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

As you can see, the response is wrong for row 0 and 4. The difference should be positive everywhere.

If I do difference only value by value then the response is positive. See the code below.

```
print df_test.loc[0]["Mention Date"] - df_test.loc[0]["Publication Date"] 
print df_test.loc[3]["Mention Date"] - df_test.loc[3]["Publication Date"] 
print type(df_test.loc[0]["Mention Date"] - df_test.loc[0]["Publication Date"]) 

121154 days, 12:47:06
106751 days 23:47:16.854700
<type 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

But the result is then of different type.

However, limit is Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225') according to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations, it should not be my case.

I have 2 questions:

1. How to overcome the "wrong" behavior?
2. Should this be considered a bug in the pandas pd.Timedelta? Or is
   this rather some 'normal' behavior?

Update: I found the limitation for pd.Timedelta https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#timedelta-limitations 
The first question remains. How to overcome this limitation? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is the limitation of timestamp, subtract with iteration i.e

```
df_test.apply(lambda x  : x['Mention Date'] - x['Publication Date'],1)

0          121154 days, 12:47:06
1              989 days 12:47:06
2           106545 days 12:47:06
3    106751 days 23:47:16.854700
4           106752 days, 0:00:00
```

Should be considered a bug? No since the pandas community specifically mentioned,

***Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years:***. Its a legit reason for a vectorized operation